# Web API [FromBody] always null

Tags: c#, webapi

Im currently creating a Web API that writes into a table. Im using [FromBody] tag to pass the values for the table.

The problem is that the [FromBody] value is always null. Im using Advanced Rest Client to test my API.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id, [FromBody]string value)
{
     //DO Something
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the type conversion. You are sending an array with one value containg a dictionary and trying to recieve a string in the method. ASP.NET can't cast your structure to `string` and use null as default value.

So, the simple way to test method is to pass a simple string in body. But the right way is to change the type of object passing into action method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id, [FromBody]List<Dictionary<string,string>> value)
{
     //DO Something
}
```

It’s strange to parse JSON manually when the system does it, but then you should pass `string` to the method. Just wrap your body to `""` and you'll get a plain JSON in the method. Also you can read body manually via `StreamReader`:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {  
        var plainBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually sir it should receive a string value then I will deserialize the value to the table format.

Comment: @user3035024 ok it’s strange to parse JSON manually when the system does it, but then you must pass the line to the method. Just wrap your body to ""

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the body deserialized, you can just read the string from the `Request.Body` property.

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(int id)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
    var bodyString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

    ...
}
```